# Writing a DLL in C/C++ for .Net interoperability

Tags: c#, interop, native

In my C# application, I would like to write a part of the code in C.
I plan to write a DLL witch would be interoperable with .Net.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are essentially three right ways to do it:

- Use C++/CLI.  This is the optimal way if this DLL is going to be used only by .NET.
- Use an "`extern "C"`" compatible API, like the Windows API itself.  This is the most portable, but isn't as convenient for your callers as using a class model to represent your objects.

  - This is the best option if you really intend to write in ANSI C (not C++).
  - For this path, you write your functions as `extern "C" returntype __stdcall __declspec(dllexport) func(params) { ... }`
  - You should also use a "caller-provides-the-buffer" memory model, rather than returning a buffer allocated inside your library.  In the cases where you do need to allocate memory for internal state, the caller should see it as an opaque handle and you should provide accessor functions for the caller to extract data.  Under no circumstances should the caller be expected to deallocate memory allocated inside your library, however it is ok for the caller to ask the library to do the deallocation.
- Use COM, or a COM-like API.  Here you return (often via out parameter) a pointer to an interface, which is a class with pure virtual functions, no non-virtual functions and no data.

  - The implementation is in concrete classes derived from this abstract interface, they can have data and helper functions galore, since that doesn't affect the binary interface.
  - This is a lot more work in the library but extremely portable and easy for the consumer to use.

And there is one thing absolutely NOT to do:

- use `__declspec(dllexport)` on C++ classes.

EDIT: I want to also explain some good practices for option #2 which will maximize portability and make the native C/C++ parts usable from unmanaged applications as well.

You can make that easier with a macro, the usual way of doing it is:

In your header file, all the function declarations look like

```
MYPROJECTAPI(returntype) PublicFunc(params);
```

In your project, the definition is

```
#define MYPROJECTAPI(returntype) \
                   extern "C" returntype __stdcall __declspec(dllexport)
```

In consumer projects

```
#define MYPROJECTAPI(returntype) \
                   extern "C" returntype __stdcall __declspec(dllimport)
```

and then you can define the macro differently for other compilers like gcc which don't use `__declspec`.

The complete solution would look like (in public header file `myproject.h`):

```
#if _WIN32
#  if BUILDMYPROJECT
#    define MYPROJECTAPI(returntype) \
         extern "C" returntype __stdcall __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define MYPROJECTAPI(returntype) \
         extern "C" returntype __stdcall __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#else
#  define MYPROJECTAPI(returntype) extern "C" returntype
#endif
```

and then your Visual C++ project would cause `BUILDMYPROJECT` to be defined when building myproject.dll

Comment: how can create a C++/CLI project with visual studio 2010?

Comment: File -> New -> Project, then Visual C++ -> CLR -> Class Library

Comment: It does'nt build. I have the followind error: 2 error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe".

Comment: Rerun the Visual Studio 2010 installer, make sure you selected to install Visual C++ tools for your platform (either x86 or amd64).  You might need the installer repair mode.

Comment: It was hard find this link, so I want to share it here (I do NOT work for this company!): http://www.xinterop.com/index.php/2015/04/30/introduction-to-the-xinterop-net-bridge/

Comment: "And there is one thing absolutely NOT to do:" Please support this statement with reasons.

Comment: I'd also like to know why that is: "And there is one thing absolutely NOT to do:"

Comment: @NiklasPeter: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797419/103167 and then consider that you're making it even *more* complex by adding .NET into the mix.

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell:

(1) Create a new C++/CLI library project.

(2) Write your code. For classes that need to be accessible from your C# project, make sure to create them as CLR classes:

```
public ref class R {/*...*/};       // CLR class
public value class V {/*...*/};     // CLR struct
public interface class I {/*...*/}; // CLR interface
```

(3) Compile the project and add a reference to it in your C# project.

Comment: how can create a C++/CLI library project with visual studio 2010?

Comment: @tinmaru: I don't have VS 2010 installed right now, but according to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fyc0azh.aspx), there should be a "CLR/Class Library" project template available.

Answer (score 1):

Through P/Invoke layer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services

Comment: This doesn't help with the DLL-writing process *at all*, which is what the question is about.

Comment: Ok. My understanding is that he was asking for a way to communicate with C/C++ dll from .NET. P/Invoke layer does that work.

Comment: The way I parse the question is "How do I do that [write a DLL which would be interoperable]?"

Comment: However in some cases Reverse P/Invoke could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example for an application where I had to do just that. In my case, I needed a DLL to wrap calls to functions that were only available in a .lib. The key part is the `extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)` in the declaration. That's basically all you need. The rest was merely using `dllimport` in the C# app and getting the marshalling right.

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) LONG EstablishContext(DWORD dwScope, 
                                                    LPCVOID pvReserved1, 
                                                    LPCVOID pvReserved2, 
                                                    LPSCARDCONTEXT phContext)
{
    return SCardEstablishContext(dwScope, pvReserved1, pvReserved2, phContext);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `__stdcall` (or equivalently, use the `WINAPI` macro).  This will simplify the p/invoke declarations considerably.