# Integrate C application with WPF

Tags: c#, c, wpf

I have been given a task to develop a Windows application that acts as a wrapper for an existing C application. The C application is controlled by the command line. I want know if it is possible to use WPF as the GUI for this application?

Comment: Sure it is possible.  What problems have you encountered so far?

Comment: Do you have the source of this application, or do you have to launch its exe from your .NET code ? In the former, the keyword you're looking for is 'interop'

Comment: Thanks for your answers, this is still in the planning stage. I do have the source code for the application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719359/c-sharp-c-interoperability

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726829/writing-a-dll-in-c-c-for-net-interoperability

Comment: There are SOOOOOO many dups for this question.

Answer (score 0):

When your app is a console application try this:

```
Process process=Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("Your.exe") {
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,    
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
});
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Your command");
var yourAnswer=process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```

this is only an simple example and maybe there are other solutions to communicate with your app. good search keyword is "IPC" :-)