# Writing a C++ DLL that a C# .NET Application can call?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli, interop

This is the situation. I am writing a backend application in C++ and my colleagues are using C# for the frontend. Basically, my backend application does image processing on images received from the C# frontend and returns a text file with data about the image.
What we were doing earlier was writing the images to disk and calling the C++ application with the file path of the image as a parameter. However, this writing/reading from disk has become a bottleneck, so we are wanting to convert the C++ application to a DLL.

At the basic level, what I want is to expose a single method from my C++ application to the C# one through a DLL (the C# application is web-based):

```
int ProcessImage(System::Bitmap^ image, System::String ^results)
```

How can I go about doing this? I am using VC++ Express 2008 and my C++ code currently compiles with CLR (although I have mixed a lot of native C++ code inside).

I have been looking around on the web, but am still stuck on how to do this. I think a C++/CLI DLL is the best option, but how do I do this?
[Writing a DLL in C/C++ for .Net interoperability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726829/writing-a-dll-in-c-c-for-net-interoperability)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++/CLI Mixed Mode DLL Creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691325/c-cli-mixed-mode-dll-creation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. What you need to do is:

1. In your C++ project, set the option in Visual C++ to compile with clr **pure**, which makes the project a C++/CLI one
2. In your C++ project, expose methods by creating a public ref class:

   ```
   public ref class Interop
   {
   public:
       //! Returns the version of this DLL
       static System::String^ GetVersion() {
           return "3.0.0.0";
       }

       //! Processes an image (passed by reference)
       System::Int32^ Process(Bitmap^ image);
   }
   ```
3. In a C# program, add a reference to the C++ DLL you compiled
4. In the C# program, call these methods (i.e. `Interop::Process(myBitmapInCS)`)

I believe this method is called "implicit P/Invoke"
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you label your C++ function as a "C" function, then it can be called by PInvoke.

Your C function will look like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Test() {
    return 1;
}
```

Your C# reference will be like this:

```
[DllImport("test.dll")]
public static extern int Test();
```

If you C++ function is an instance member, then you can still do it but it requires some tricks.

Comment: You should also add __stdcall to the C++ function, or CallingConvention to the DllImport

Comment: I believe that extern "C" prevents function/method name mangling.

Comment: Only functions in the global namespace can be exported in a way that's compatible with p/invoke.  Forget about anything having to do with classes, whether you mean member functions of classes (static or not) or class types in parameters or return values.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think this will work with what I am trying to do. How can I use this method to pass the image by reference and receive results as a string?